# Bundle.js ReactJS file beautify

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've build a project with pure **reactJS** using `create-react-app` and I successfully uploaded the app to my server but unfortunately I've lost my laptop and all of my data :( but my project working on the site my question is:

**Is it possible to get my project back again to development mode through existing files?**

Comment: I think it is not, because the code is transpiled to ES5 by babel, and then bundled into a single file by webpack. Also, webpack might compress it, so it is practically non-human-readable, and I doubt there might be a way to get the original files back from a bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use https://github.com/1egoman/debundle to un-bundle the index.js file (in the case of create-react-app, Webpack is the bundler).  If the bundled file was built in production mode, you may need to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/unuglify-js to get it back in somewhat readable order.

Sorry to point you to libraries which may or may not work, but the truth is that you may be better starting from scratch--the real knowledge in your mind, not in the source code.  You may be able to throw in some improvements the second time around... look at the bright side!

Comment: Did this help you?  Were you able to rescue the project, or did you end up starting from scratch?

Comment: I'm starting from scratch :(

Answer (score 0):

solution in here: [Can I use a sourcemap and bundle file to retrieve original react code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119322/can-i-use-a-sourcemap-and-bundle-file-to-retrieve-original-react-code)

THIS IS 90% fix.

Publish the APP so you can access it through browser (e.g. NETLIFY, can publish by accessing your Git repo) -> open the published project in the browser -> then inside the browser press  ctrl + shift + i  (chrome and pc).

This gives you access to developer tools.

Find: SOURCES TAB

on left hand side you will see folder structure -> click into  STATIC

Now you can see all CONTENT inside JS files and CSS by clicking on them.

You can now either copy and paste them into you IDE or download them by right clicking them and Save As.