# can I convert static build files to pre compiled js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have my public folder deleted build but I have my build folder with the static files so is there a way to convert the static js css files to my previous pre build files. This happened while deploying my app to firebase.

Please help those were a lot of files that I lost

Answer (score 0):

So I was just searching when I stumbled upon this solution (which is solved my problem).
just look in to static folder in inspect of your site and you should have you folders and files exactly as it was in your comp.

[Here is the link to the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119322/can-i-use-a-sourcemap-and-bundle-file-to-retrieve-original-react-code)